# Printing a certain struct produces unexpected output

Tags: c, struct

I am writing this struct to put a group of pairable symbols.

```c
struct pairable_symbol {
    char symbol;
    char** pairables;
};
```

I initialised an array of pairable_symbol struct like this and made a pairing function:

```c
struct pairable_symbol* pairable_symbols;

void pair_symbol(struct pairable_symbol *pairable_symbol_ptr, const char symbol, const int param_size, ...) {
    va_list param_pointer;
    va_start(param_pointer, param_size);
    printf("Pairing %c with", symbol);
    pairable_symbol_ptr->symbol = symbol;
    pairable_symbol_ptr->pairables = malloc(sizeof(char*) * param_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < param_size; i++) {
        pairable_symbol_ptr->pairables[i] = va_arg(param_pointer, char*);
        printf(" %s", pairable_symbol_ptr->pairables[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    va_end(param_pointer);
}
```

This `pair_symbol` function will initialise an instance of `pairable_symbol` with the specified parameters. So, I proceed to use this function in my main function.

```c
    pairable_symbols = malloc(sizeof(pairable_symbols) * 11);

    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[0], '+', 2, "+", "=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[1], '-', 2, "-", "=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[2], '*', 2, "=", "/");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[3], '/', 3, "=", "/", "*");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[4], '<', 2, "<", "<=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[5], '>', 2, ">", ">=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[6], '!', 1, "=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[7], '&', 2, "&", "=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[8], '|', 2, "|", "=");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[9], '.', 1, "..");
    pair_symbol(&pairable_symbols[10], '\\', 1, "\n");
```

While assigning the struct, it will print out the parameter that I have passed to the function.

However, `pairable_symbol[6]` produces an unexpected output like this:

> '!'airing �+tBV =

The others print out the expected output. For example, `pairable_symbol[0]` prints the following line:

> Pairing + with + =

What is the error in my code that causes this unexpected output at `pairable_symbol[6]`?

A relevant paste:

- [Pairable Symbols](https://pastebin.com/n5CQbXQK) - A full code that produces this unexpected output.

Comment: Would be better if you would post compilable code, including all `#include` and `int main()`. Guessing includes is no fun.

Comment: Thanks, I have included a paste link.

Comment: Why don't you free() the allocated memory before leaving the function? Do you think that the pointer to the allocated memory is somehow passed back to main()? If so, that's yet another severe bug. But looking at your complete code, it rather just looks like the function has tons of memory leaks, which is also a bug but less severe.

Comment: Unrelated to the bugs, you should strongly consider dropping the va_list in favour for a struct parameter or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am new to C. This is an early program that I write in C, and I'm making sure that those initializers are called exactly once. Doesn't the system recover all allocated memory at program exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sizeof(pairable_symbols)
```

is the size of the pointer, not the size of structure. You want:

```
pairable_symbols = malloc(sizeof(struct pairable_symbol) * 11);
```

or:

```
pairable_symbols = malloc(sizeof(*pairable_symbols) * 11);
```

> What is the error in my code that causes this unexpected output at pairable_symbol[6]?

It happens on your architecture that `sizeof(struct pairable_symbol*) * 11 =~ sizeof(*pairable_symbols) * 5` and somewhere around 5th element assignment the stack get's overflowed.